# Interpretation of ur.df - "p-value"?

Tags: r, time-series, unit-root, augmented-dickey-fuller

When applying the "urca" package function `ur.df`, like

```
summary(ur.df(data$col1, type = c("none"), lags = 12, selectlags = c("AIC")))
```

I get following result:

```
############################################### 
# Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test Unit Root Test # 
############################################### 

Test regression trend 


Call:
lm(formula = z.diff ~ z.lag.1 + 1 + tt + z.diff.lag)

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-12928366  -2888728   1284718   4218373   7179531 

Coefficients:
                 Estimate    Std. Error  t value  Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)  5.391984e+07  1.638362e+07  3.29108 0.0043123 **
z.lag.1     -2.438154e+00  7.557134e-01 -3.22629 0.0049588 **
tt           6.579260e+05  2.730453e+05  2.40959 0.0275861 * 
z.diff.lag1  1.712004e+00  6.595980e-01  2.59553 0.0188537 * 
z.diff.lag2  1.402824e+00  6.379412e-01  2.19899 0.0420083 * 
z.diff.lag3  1.321555e+00  5.294537e-01  2.49607 0.0231329 * 
z.diff.lag4  1.099430e+00  4.720412e-01  2.32910 0.0324428 * 
z.diff.lag5  8.132753e-01  4.181477e-01  1.94495 0.0685140 . 
z.diff.lag6  1.797331e-01  3.654326e-01  0.49184 0.6291254   
z.diff.lag7  5.890640e-01  2.939590e-01  2.00390 0.0612825 . 
z.diff.lag8  3.919041e-01  2.794371e-01  1.40248 0.1787705   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 6708593 on 17 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7237276, Adjusted R-squared:  0.5613144 
F-statistic: 4.253547 on 10 and 17 DF,  p-value: 0.003348755


Value of test-statistic is: -3.2263 3.9622 5.2635 

Critical values for test statistics: 
      1pct  5pct 10pct
tau3 -4.15 -3.50 -3.18
phi2  7.02  5.13  4.31
phi3  9.31  6.73  5.61
```

Now the question:

1. I do understand that "-3.2263" is the critical value (t-value)
2. **There is a unit root** with trend since -3.2263 > -3.18 (tau3@10pct)
   This means the time-series is **non-stationary** at a 10% significance level.
3. But, what is the meaning of "p-value: 0.003348755"? Should I list this value in a table summarizing my unit root test results or rather mark the 0.1 significance level (*10%)?

The [documentation](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/urca/docs/ur.df) says that critical values are based on Hamilton (1994) and Dickey and Fuller (1981)".

Comment: There's a lot of mistakes in your question (mistaken ideas, mistaken calculations/values), but Richard's answer mentions some of them so I'll leave them aside for now. If your main question is "what does the p-value mean?", note that there are many threads on site relating to what p-values mean, and these may be helpful. Potential search terms would include things like  *meaning p-value* or *interpret p-value*; if you're specifically interested in interpretations in relation to regression, terms like  *meaning p-value regression* or *interpret p-value regression* may be better, and so on.

Answer (score 5):

1. `-3.2263` is a test statistic `tau3`, *not* a critical value. The corresponding critical values are listed under "Critical values" (no wonder) in the row beginning with `tau3`.
2. At 95% confidence level you *cannot* reject the null hypothesis of presence of unit root -- since the test statistic is *greater* than the respective critical value, `-3.2263 > -3.50`.
   Meanwhile, at 90% confidence level you *can* reject the null hypothesis of presence of unit root -- since the test statistic is *lesser* than the respective critical value, `-3.2263 < -3.18`.
3. `p-value: 0.003348755` is associated with the overall significance of the regression model used for testing for the presence of the unit root. It is *not* associated with the statistical significance of the `tau3` statistic which is the relevant one in the unit root test. I am not sure if reporting it would be useful.